# Adding events to google calendar using php without login by more than one user

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have all client ID, Client secret, API key, Authorization code for tokens etc which is generated by google API console. And also I have activated calendar service. I have made a team of 2 persons that can edit one calendar. Now, I would like to code in such a way that both of them can add their events to that calendar without login to their accounts. It is asking for login to view the calendar and obviously cannot add event. I was referred many tutorials like for oauth 2.0 etc bt not getting exact idea then. Will it be possible?

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");
// Visit code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('client id');
$client->setClientSecret('cliet secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('my calendar url generated after clicking to HTML button');
$calendarListEntry = new Google_CalendarListEntry("My calendar entry");
$calendarListEntry->setId("ajoshi.kraff@gmail.com");
$createdCalendarListEntry = $cal->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

Answer (score 0):

Such situation is described [in google docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver).

After the user provides correct credentials, google oauth server redirects him to your service and provides an **access token** (which you can use right away to sign your requests) and a **refresh token** which you can use to get new access tokens. You will have to get new access tokens because they expire. Refresh token lets you get new access token without user's presence - in your background services for example. So you should store the refresh token in the db (or anywhere you want).

Check out this docs page:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Well thanks a lot @Sergey Eremin but I am getting error something like "Call to a member function insert() on a non-object ..." ..

Comment: It is impossible to say what is wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Well thanks now that error is solved .. Now the error comes like "Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key=......." . Please help me for it. I was also get new api key.

Comment: It is problem for file "\google-api-client\src\io\Google_REST.php"

Comment: <?php
require_once 'google-api-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
 $client->setClientId('client id');
 $client->setClientSecret('cliet secret');
 $client->setRedirectUri('my calendar url generated after clicking to HTML button');

Comment: $calendarListEntry = new Google_CalendarListEntry("My calendar entry");
  $calendarListEntry->setId("ajoshi.kraff@gmail.com");

  $createdCalendarListEntry = $cal->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

  echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();

Comment: The code does not seem complete.. $cal is not defined for example

Comment: Yeah I have defined all it.. Actually I cnt post whole code .. $cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
} Like this..